# How to handle 'force close' due late response time from server

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, forceclose

I have an android app in which there are many scenarios where request and response happens to-from server. For example:`login` i.e. `authentication`. When user enters `username` and `password`, then the credentials are verified against the one responded by Server.

But sometimes what happens is that due to slow network the response comes late and android pop-up a force close dialog box, which is highly embarrassing.

I was thinking that is there a way to segregate the code which hits the server in some separate thread and till it gets me a response. I may show a progress bar instead of force close. Is it a good solution?

Example code:

```
//this code will be called when user presses Login button on UI
public void authenticate(View view) {
      //the logic for authentication
      if(authentication==true){
         //go to home page
        }
}
```

In the above code how can I separate the logic for authentication so that force close does not occur when response is late as expected.

I would also appreciate any other better approach to tackle such scenarios of force close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not include any task which takes time to execute in your main thread. You should do httpCommunication in different thread. and it will avoid this ANR.

What docs says >>
*In Android, application responsiveness is monitored by the Activity Manager and Window Manager system services. Android will display the ANR dialog for a particular application when it detects one of the following conditions:
    No response to an input event (e.g. key press, screen touch) within 5 seconds
    A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds*

Read this document specially created for [Designing for responsiveness and to avoid ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html)

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `AsyncTask` or http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Show a progress dialog on UI meanwhile. Provide a callback function which will be called once response from server is received.

Answer (score 0):

Use below sample code to do a `login` process. You can use `AsyncTask` to do the login process.

The `LoginActivity` class, which uses `AsyncTask`.

- On `Login` button click, I am `executing` the `AsyncTask`.
- During the login process, this will display a `ProgressDialog`
- After the process completion, dismisses the `ProgressDialog`and displays a status message to user

The class code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private Button login_Button = null;
    private EditText userNameText = null;
    private EditText passwordText = null;
    private String uName = "";
    private String pass = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_login);
        login_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdDoLogin);

        userNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        login_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                uName = userNameText.getText().toString().trim();
                pass = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (uName.equals("") || pass.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                            "Fill both username and password fields",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    new LoginActivity.DoLoginProcess().execute(); // calling the AsyncTask here
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class DoLoginProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        ProgressDialog pd = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Logging In...");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int loginStatus = 0 ; // treat this as loginStatus. 0 = login failed; 1=login success. You can return this value to onPostExecute function

            //*********************************************
            // do login process over internet here. Hope you already have the code to do the login process over internet.
            //*********************************************         

            return loginStatus;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer status) {
            super.onPostExecute(status);
            pd.dismiss(); // dismiss the progress dialog

            if (status == 0) { // login failed
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        LoginActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Login failed");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                alertDialog.show();
            } else if(status == 1) { // login success
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        LoginActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Success");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Login success");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The `test_login` layout XMl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loginbglayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/holderLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cmdDoLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Login" >
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```